# Should View components like Buttons, Edittexts, Textview, etc. be static or not (Android Studio)

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, static

Can someone explain me if it's better to have Buttons and other components in Android Studio as static attributes or is it better to have these as just normal attributes, when you look at an activity that is only used once at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't want to use views in static variables cause when activities are recreated they will be destroyed and your static views will still hold your destroyed context. This will cause lots of bug in application and is considerably very bad tactic and not even that much useful.

Comment: but what if you reassign these static variables when the activity is created so everytime the activity gets opened again it's gonna have the new components as its attributes

Comment: Imagine complex layout you would need to reassign more than ten or at least twenty static variables now imagine more or less complex app with twenty screens and multiply that number. let's say you do that and ignore the fact that you are adding just boilerplate, what do you get from that? What would it give and in which case would it be more flexible or helpful than normal instance variables.